# How to change string img with value on alt

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove the img tag and replace it with the value of the alt

```
var data="how are you <img src='blabla/emot/smile.gif' alt=':)'> yes <img src='blabla/emot/smile.gif' alt=':)'> <img src='blabla/emot/melet.gif' alt=':P'>";
```

to the final result

```
var data="how are you :) yes :) :P";
```

I want to eliminate the img tag and replace it with values ​​in alt , using jQuery or javascript

Comment: Could you please translate the main body text to English?

Comment: How do you generate the code? I can not see the real problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with jQuery one-liner:

```
var data = "how are you <img src='blabla/emot/smile.gif' alt=':)'> yes <img src='blabla/emot/smile.gif' alt=':)'> <img src='blabla/emot/melet.gif' alt=':P'>";

var result =
    $('<div>').html(data)                 // create `<div>` and put data as contents
              .find('img')                // find `<img>` elements in `<div>`
              .replaceWith(function() {   // replace `<img>` elements
                  return this.alt;        // with their `alt` attributes
              })
              .end()                      // return back to `<div>` element
              .text();                    // get text contents

console.log( result );  // "how are you :) yes :) :P"
```